# Trying to install dual boot for Win10

Tags: system-installation

I keep getting "No Signal on my monitor after selecting "Install Ubuntu".  Pls help.

Comment: What is the result when you use ***Try Ubuntu***.

Comment: You can try this [Changing the CD Boot Option Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD_Boot_Option_Configuration_Line).

Comment: I don't even get a menu like that...

Comment: @vembutech Not relevant for newer systems. Telenstac, please edit and update your question with hardware specs as some notebooks may require additional steps for a UEFI dualboot. No video suggests, however, the presence of a graphics card not supported by the default drivers in which case you'd need to add the `nomodeset`boot parameter until the proprietary drivers are installed.